# What are metadata tokens in obj files?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I came across on linker error of c++ cli:

> Error  LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c00019d).  foo.obj 1
>
> Error  LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0001ab).  bar.obj 1

What is actually metadata tokens? I have learned obj files via `ildasm`, but I have no idea what is actually problem. Here is brief content:

> foo.obj:

```
// TypeDef #190 (020000bf)
// -------------------------------------------------------
//  TypDefName: FooClass  (020000BF)
//  Flags     : [Public] [SequentialLayout] [Class] [Sealed] [AnsiClass] [BeforeFieldInit]  (00100109)
//  Extends   : 01000017 [TypeRef] System.ValueType
//  Layout    : Packing:0, Size:12
//  CustomAttribute #1 (0c00019c)
//  -------------------------------------------------------
//      CustomAttribute Type: 0a000006
//      CustomAttributeName: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NativeCppClassAttribute :: instance void .ctor()
//      Length: 4
//      Value : 01 00 00 00                                      >                <
//      ctor args: ()
// 
//  CustomAttribute #2 (0c00019d)
//  -------------------------------------------------------
//      CustomAttribute Type: 0a000007
//      CustomAttributeName: System.CLSCompliantAttribute :: instance void .ctor(bool)
//      Length: 5
//      Value : 01 00 00 00 00                                   >                <
//      ctor args: ( <can not decode> )
```

> bar.obj

```
// TypeDef #199 (020000c8)
// -------------------------------------------------------
//  TypDefName: FooClass  (020000C8)
//  Flags     : [Public] [SequentialLayout] [Class] [Sealed] [AnsiClass] [BeforeFieldInit]  (00100109)
//  Extends   : 01000016 [TypeRef] System.ValueType
//  Layout    : Packing:0, Size:12
//  CustomAttribute #1 (0c0001aa)
//  -------------------------------------------------------
//      CustomAttribute Type: 0a000006
//      CustomAttributeName: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NativeCppClassAttribute :: instance void .ctor()
//      Length: 4
//      Value : 01 00 00 00                                      >                <
//      ctor args: ()
// 
//  CustomAttribute #2 (0c0001ab)
//  -------------------------------------------------------
//      CustomAttribute Type: 0a000007
//      CustomAttributeName: System.CLSCompliantAttribute :: instance void .ctor(bool)
//      Length: 5
//      Value : 01 00 00 00 00                                   >                <
//      ctor args: ( <can not decode> )
```

All I see, that FooClass extends different ValueTypes (I don't know why). Is there any documentation about that tokens? Is it some kind of pdb information about symbols?

Comment: Showing us the code in question will probably be more useful than showing us an intermediate compile output. But that said, this type of error is because a class is declared in two locations in different ways. Often it's because a header file uses a #define in the class declaration, and it gets #defined as two different things.